# How to change a QLineEdit bullet's color in password mode

Tags: python, pyqt

I would like to have a "Confirm password" line edit whose bullet points turn to red when the passwords don't match. Is there a way to change the bullet color?

My current attempt is:

```
class CreateUserDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        layout.addSpacing(30)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Create a new account", self))

        self.username_edit = QLineEdit(parent=self)
        self.username_edit.setPlaceholderText("Username")
        layout.addWidget(self.username_edit)

        self.pwd_edit = QLineEdit(parent=self)
        self.pwd_edit.setPlaceholderText("Password")
        self.pwd_edit.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        layout.addWidget(self.pwd_edit)

        self.confirm_pwd_edit = QLineEdit(parent=self)
        self.confirm_pwd_edit.setPlaceholderText("Confirm password")
        self.confirm_pwd_edit.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        layout.addWidget(self.confirm_pwd_edit)

        self.pwd_edit.textChanged.connect(self.checkPasswordMatches)
        self.confirm_pwd_edit.textChanged.connect(
            self.checkPasswordMatches)

    def checkPasswordMatches(self, text):
        if not self.pwd_edit.text() == self.confirm_pwd_edit.text():
            palette = qt.QPalette()
            palette.setColor(qt.QPalette.Text, qt.Qt.red)
            self.confirm_pwd_edit.setPalette(palette)
        else:
            # restore normal style
            self.confirm_pwd_edit.setPalette(
                self.username_edit.palette())
```

This actually works on the placeholder text, but not on the bullets when the user starts typing.

Comment: Actually my solution only works on placeholder text and never on the actual text, no matter if in password mode. The text color is always the one from my stylesheet.

But I would like to not change my stylesheet, if possible (it's long, it's defined in a parent QLineEdit class, and it's currently not a public attribute but just a local variable).

Comment: Stylesheets override the palette settings. So as long as you define the text color in the stylesheet, there is nothing you can do besides modifying that stylesheet to get a color change.

Comment: @PiRK some feedback?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I'm not very familiar with qproperties, so I used the less elegant solution of changing the color in the stylesheet and reapplying the stylesheet directly.

Comment: Like @Felix mentionned, my main issue was that my stylesheet was overriding the palette thing that i was trying to do. I should have mentionned right away that I was applying a stylesheet, but I was not aware that it was interfering.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a pyqtProperty that indicates that the password is valid or not.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

qss = '''
ValidationLineEdit[echoMode="2"][isValid="true"] {
    color: green;
}
ValidationLineEdit[echoMode="2"][isValid="false"] {
    color: red;
}
'''

class ValidationLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    valid_length_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        valid_length = 0
        if kwargs.get("valid_length"):
            valid_length = kwargs.pop("valid_length")
        super(ValidationLineEdit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._valid_length_ = valid_length
        self.textChanged.connect(self.update_stylesheet)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(bool)
    def isValid(self):
        if self.valid_length == 0: return False
        return len(self.text()) == self.valid_length

    def update_stylesheet(self):
        self.style().unpolish(self)
        self.style().polish(self)

    def valid_length(self):
        return self._valid_length_

    def set_valid_length(self, lenght):
        if self._valid_length_ == lenght: return
        self._valid_length_ = lenght
        self.valid_length_changed.emit(lenght)

    valid_length = QtCore.pyqtProperty(int, fget=valid_length, fset=set_valid_length, notify=valid_length_changed)


class CreateUserDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CreateUserDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.username_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText="Username")
        self.pwd_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(placeholderText="Password", echoMode=QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.confirm_pwd_edit = ValidationLineEdit(placeholderText="Confirm password", echoMode=QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addSpacing(30)
        lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Create a new account"))
        lay.addWidget(self.username_edit)
        lay.addWidget(self.pwd_edit)
        lay.addWidget(self.confirm_pwd_edit)

        self.pwd_edit.editingFinished.connect(self.on_editingFinished)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_editingFinished(self):
        self.confirm_pwd_edit.valid_length = len(self.pwd_edit.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    w =  CreateUserDialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```